# How to put table in a table?

Tags: html

I need to make a table with more tables, but i dont know how to put this tables inside
[image]
It should look like this

**i need to do this without CSS**

I have tried something...well it turns out like this

[image]

I don't understand how to make it

Comment: Just put a `<table>` element inside the `<td>`. Tables inside tables work exactly the same as tables anywhere else. There is literally no difference

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Your second image looks better than the first one

Answer (score 2):

This is a `HTML` lesson for tables as well as `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <td>spaltenweise</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <td colspan="4">A04_03a</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>Spale 1</td>
                    <td>Spalte 2</td>
                    <td>Spalte 3</td>
                    <td>Spalte 4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">Spalte 1+2+3+4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <td colspan="4">A04_03b</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>Spale 1</td>
                    <td>Spalte 2</td>
                    <td>Spalte 3</td>
                    <td>Spalte 4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Spalte 1+2</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Spalte 3+4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td> 
        <td>
            <table>
                <td colspan="4">A04_03c</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>Spalte 1</td>
                    <td>Spalte 2</td>
                    <td>Spalte 3</td>
                    <td>Spalte 4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="1">Spalte 1</td>
                    <td colspan="3">Spalte 2+3+4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <tr>
            <td>zeilenweise</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr colspan="3">A04_03d</tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Zeile 1</td>
                        <td rowspan="4">Zeile 1+2+3+4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Zeile 2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Zeile 3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Zeile 4</td>
                    </tr>  
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr colspan="3">A04_03e</tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Zeile 1</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">Zeile 2+3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Zeile 2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr colspan="3"></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Zeile 3</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">Zeile 2+3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Zeile 4</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr colspan="3">A04_03f</tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Zeile 1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Zeile 1</td>
                        <td rowspan="3">Zeile 2+3+4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Zeile 3</td>
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Zeile 4</td>   
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
   <table>

<tr>
  <td style="border:1px solid black;">
  Spaltenweise
  </td>
  <td style="border:1px solid black;">
  
  
<table>
<tr>
<td style="border:1px solid black;">
  A04
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="border:1px solid black;">
   100
  </td>
  <td style="border:1px solid black;">
    200
  </td>
  <td style="border:1px solid black;">
    300
  </td>
</tr>
<tr >
<td colspan=3 style="border:1px solid black;">
  spalte 1 2 3 4
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
  </td>
</tr>


</table>
```

Comment: 15K rep and no snippet and no explanation?